# Get RecordStore data from an external middlet

Tags: java, java-me, midlet, recordstore

Is there any form to get the data of the recordstore from an external middlet ?

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible if the MIDlets are in the same MIDlet suite (i.e. they are in the same .jar file), then the MIDlets share the same record stores.

Otherwise, it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible, while creating a `RecordStore` , if you set the second argument of its `openRecrdStore()` as true then it is possible to access the `RecordStore` from another independent Midlet.